# Gas Dispersal Simulation in Rviz

Tags: ros, simulation, rviz, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everybody
Now I am stduying International Master’s Thesis of Gas Dispersal Simulation in ROS by Ali Abdul Khaliq，I want to creat a package of Odor simulator,In thesis has a download link of Odor simulator package,but it can't work.If you have this package would you please sent it to my email .Thank you very much.My email is 247587757@qq.com.By the way,If you have a code of follow picture ,it also can sent to me !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61580/gas-dispersal-simulation-in-rviz/) by [student](https://answers.ros.org/users/4765/student/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Unfortunately the code is not published yet! the svn link given in the thesis is the universities private server and therefore is not accessible from outside the university. If you need it urgently, just search my webpage "ali abdul khaliq" and send me an email.

---

Originally posted by [Ali Abdul Khaliq](https://answers.ros.org/users/414/ali-abdul-khaliq/) with karma: 63 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [king](https://answers.ros.org/users/8851/king/) on 2013-11-15**:
Hi，I have send an email on your facebook。If you convenience on time，Please send code to my email 。Thank you very much ，Eamil ：kingofhy@gmail.com。